# Virtualenv installs envs into local/bin instead of bin

Tags: python3, 22.04, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

**Problem:**

The `bin` directory of my virtual environment produced with `virtualenvwrapper` (which uses `virtualenv` under the hood) is located in the subfolder`local` instead which leads to breakage across the board (mostly `virtualenvwrapper` and `vscode` for now).
Basically, these tools expect the interpreter in `<envname>/bin` and not in `<envname>/local/bin`.

**Infos:**

I already did some research and found the following:

- There was a change in Ubuntu 22.04 that now uses `posix_local` in module `sysconfig` instead of `posix_prefix` as the default scheme which was explained [here](https://lists.debian.org/debian-python/2022/03/msg00039.html)
- Virtualenv at some point introduced a patch for Python 2 that changed the `bin` location to `local/bin` inside a virtual environment in response to the `posix_local` prefix, which was asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227120/strange-local-folder-inside-virtualenv-folder) and resulted in [this patch](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/pull/166) which was supposed to fix [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/839588)

**System:**

- Ubuntu 22.04 LTS x86_64
- python3 - 3.10.4-0ubuntu2
- python3-virtualenv - 20.13.0+ds-2
- virtualenvwrapper==4.8.4

**Question:**

- How do I get `virtualenv` to install my environment into `<envname>/bin` again, ignoring `posix_local` option?
- Is the reason why this was fixed still applicable for Python 3? (I must admit I did not really understand the reason why the patch was necessary in the first place.)

Comment: I opened a related [issue on github](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/2340), regarding the idea to use `venv` as creator of environment via `virtualenv`. This is still broken atm.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Original Answer

The user [yingmanwumen](https://github.com/yingmanwumen) over on the GitHub of [virtualenv](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv) posted a solution in [this issue](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/2350):

Basically, they changed the sysconfig scheme by exporting the following variable in their shell of choice:

```bash
export DEB_PYTHON_INSTALL_LAYOUT='deb'
```

This changes the default installation scheme from `posix_local`, which produced the problematic behavior, to `deb_system`, which has the normal/expected virtual environment layout again.
The current installation scheme can be checked with this snipped:

```py
import sysconfig
print(sysconfig.get_default_scheme())
```

It should be noted that this is a temporary solution.
A real solution would probably include changing this behavior in `virtualenv` itself. [yingmanwumen's issue](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/2350) as well as [my own issue](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/2340) address problems with the `posix_local` scheme. The developers of `virtualenv` are open to accepting a PR to resolve the underlying issue.
I will update this answer if a PR is proposed and accepted that resolves it.

---

## Update

A [PR](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/pull/2415) was accepted solving this issue specifically for `virtualenv`, meaning that all versions of `virtualenv > 20.16.5` should not have this problem anymore.

Additionally, it seems the bug happens specifically if:

> **[...]** python3-distutils is not installed (or when not using the [deadsnakes](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) fork)

according to the proposer of [the PR](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/pull/2415).
So either installing `python3-distutils` or using the version of the [deadsnakes](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) fork should also fix this problem if it is encountered.

Lastly, efforts are taken to address this issue also in Debian/Ubuntu and with making the `posix_prefix` scheme more robust in general. This wasn't the first issue that happened due to confusing installation schemes as can be seen [in this discussion](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/2208).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you, and whilst I dont have the answers to your questions I did find that switching to venv solved my issues within a few minutes...
It seems to be the modern, preferred 'one' way to manage python virtual environments.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573587/what-is-the-difference-between-venv-pyvenv-pyenv-virtualenv-virtualenvwrappe)

[How to setup venv](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-programming-environment-on-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however there are two problems that I have with switching to `venv` from `virtualenv`:
1) `venv` is seemingly a subset of `virtualenv` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64586483). Especially creating environments with different Python versions might be finicky otherwise.
2) I personally use `virtualenvwrapper` and it seems it is not designed to wrap `venv` instead of `virtualenv`. It is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45826517/python-venv-and-virtualenvwrapper-combined) but there does not seem to be a definitive answer.

Comment: I read the same thing about virtualenvwrapper and venv - i agree its not super clear, but I can confirm it does work. Which versions of python are you using? I am only using python 3 (3.10) which maybe why my scenario is easier.
I am picking this project up after a long break hence things have broken and ive forgotten things. My approach is get it working as fast as possible and the understanding will follow... Im definitely not satisfied yet!

Comment: FWIW these are my environment variables i need to set:


export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/environments

export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3

export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv

source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_ENV_BIN_DIR=bin


Seems that virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper are still very much being used in someway!
My confusion continues :)

Comment: VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_ENV_BIN_DIR is being overwritten in virtualenvwrapper.sh, so you have to set if *after* sourcing, as you do, but I had to set it to VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_ENV_BIN_DIR="local/bin" because `virtualenv` still puts the bin directory into <name>/local.
This fixes `virtualenvwrapper` but other programs, like `vscode`, still expect the interpreter in <name>/bin.
I am not convinced that working around the local/bin directory is the correct move for me. My original question still stands.

Comment: I am using `virtualenvwrapper` which I still want to use, so I tried the following, inspired by your use of `venv`:

Tried using an alias -`alias mkvirtualenv="mkvirtualenv --creator=venv"` - using `venv` as creator for `virtualenv`, because `venv` does not install into `local/bin`. This is [completely broken](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/2340) at the moment.

I am currently overwriting it like so: `mkvirtualenv() { python3 -m venv "$HOME/.virtualenvs/$1" }`. This works for now but is *not* want I ultimately want.
I *would* like to use `virtualenv`...

Answer (score 1):

A "solution" that worked for me was to downgrade setuptools:
pip install setuptools==59.6.0